# Saving roles from mentioned user

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a tempmute command, I followed a tutorial online which worked... But my own server has users with multiple roles, and these roles allow them to talk even when they receive the "muted" role.

Is there any way to save all the roles from a mentioned user and then to remove and add those roles?

I already tried to make a new let variable

```
let roleHistory = tomute.member.roles;
```

and then adding and removing them with:

```
await(tomute.removerole(roleHistory));

tomute.addRole(roleHistory);
```

But that didn't work

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));

  if(!tomute) return message.reply("Couldn't find user.");
  if(tomute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Can't mute them!");
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "muted");

  if(!muterole){
    try{
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "muted",
        color: "#000000",
        permissions:[]
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false
        });
      });
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }

  let mutetime = args[1];
  if(!mutetime) return message.reply("You didn't specify a time!");

  await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));

  message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutetime))}`);

  setTimeout(function(){
    tomute.removeRole(muterole.id);

    message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> has been unmuted!`);
  }, ms(mutetime));

}
```

I want the bot to take the roles away, tempmute the user and giving the roles back after the Timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is on the right track, but you missed a small detail. A Guild Member has a method `addRole` and `removeRole` which you used. However, these methods are meant for adding/removing a single role.

When you first fetch the user roles with `let roleHistory = tomute.member.roles;`, it returns a `Collection` of roles. If you then attempt to use `removeRole(roleHistory)` it attempts to remove a single role equal to the complete collection (which doesn't exist obviously).

To make it work, you need the methods [`addRoles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRoles) and [`removeRoles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRoles) which adds/removes an entire collection. So your code would be:

```
let roleHistory = tomute.roles;

// Removing all the roles
await(tomute.removeRoles(roleHistory));

// Adding all the roles
tomute.addRoles(roleHistory);
```

P.s. Since your `tomute` variable is already a user you need to change your code to fetch the roles from `let roleHistory = tomute.member.roles;` to `let roleHistory = tomute.roles;`